# What happens if I don't catch a throw?

Tags: c++

This is super basic but I can't find the answer anywhere. There's lots of posts out there about throwing and catching, but what actually happens if I `throw` from `function1` and then call `function1` from `function2` but don't catch it, does that mean it just gets rethrown to the caller of `function2`? Judging from the following I'd say yes, but I wanted to get a solid guru-like answer before I soldier on and assume:

```
#include <iostream>

void function1()
{
    throw 1;
}

void function2()
{
    function1();
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        function2();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "caught!";
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`Output:
caught!`

Comment: Um, scope and function calls nest. So nothing is really re-thrown. Exceptions are (as a first approximation) caught at the innermost scope.

Comment: http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/stackunwinding.php - if you want to know how it work in details.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, that's how exceptions work. When an exception is thrown, it is caught by the topmost function in the call stack that has a handler for that exception in the scope of execution. Since you are going back to a function lower in the stack, some variables in the scope of the functions in the upper stack frames need to get out of scope, and therefore their destructors are called. This is called stack unwinding. It is really nice to combine that and RAII (lookup RAII if you don't know what that is). However, If any destructor throws an exception during stack unwinding, then it is bad and the `std::terminate` function will be called. Typically your program will then end (and this is why you are always advised to write non-throwing destructors).

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw):

> Once the exception object is constructed, the control flow works
>   backwards (up the call stack) until it reaches the start of a try
>   block, at which point the parameters of the associated catch blocks
>   are compared with the thrown expression to find a match. If no match
>   is found, the control flow continues to unwind the stack until the
>   next try block, and so on. If a match is found, the control flow jumps
>   to the matching catch block (the exception handler), which executes
>   normally.
>
> As the control flow moves up the call stack, destructors are invoked
>   for all objects with automatic storage duration constructed since the
>   corresponding try-block was entered, in reverse order of construction.
>   If an exception is thrown from a constructor, destructors are called
>   for all fully-constructed non-static non-variant members and base
>   classes. This process is called stack unwinding.

Answer (score 11):

Since `function2()` and `function1()` don't catch the exception it will *propagate* up the call stack until it is caught by the first suitable handler which you have in `main()`. Local objects destructors are being called along the way which is called *stack unwinding*. If you didn't have a suitable handler the C++ runtime would call `unexpected()` built-in function that would call `abort()` and terminate the program.

Comment: ... and if there is no handler then the stack isn't required to be unwound. I think it's implementation-defined whether it is or not, but it might be unspecified.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but it doesn't get "rethrown" - simply, when you throw an exception it will walk the call stack until it can find a `catch` block that can handle it; this is one of the most important "selling points" of exceptions.

If no suitable handler is found, `std::terminate` is called and your program terminates abnormally (notice that in this case it's not guaranteed that destructors will be called).

Comment: Exactly. An exception is **rethrown** if it's first caught by a `catch` block, and then thrown again by the `catch` block, possibly after some processing (such as noting the exception in a log file). If an exception is uncaught, it gets **propagated** down the call stack, as sharptooth said, but using "up" for "down". :)

Answer (score 5):

> does that mean it just gets rethrown to the caller of function2?

No, it's not rethrown; the original `throw` sends it as far up the call stack as necessary until a handler is found. In this case, there's no handler in `function1` or `function2`, so it ends up in the handler in `main`.

If it's not caught at all, and tries to leave `main`, then the program will terminate. (There are ways to change that behaviour, but that's not particularly relevant to this question).

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

void function1()
{
    try
    {
        throw 1;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception caught in function1." << std::endl;
        throw 1;
    }
}

void function2()
{
    try
    {
        function1();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception caught in function2." << std::endl;
        throw 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        function2();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception caught in main." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Exception caught in function1.
Exception caught in function2.
Exception caught in main.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could throw without any try and catch block. For example,

```
std::string &someClass::operator[](unsigned position) {
   // try {
   if (position <= length && position >= 0) {
       //return string at that position;
   }else{
       throw ("out of range");
   }
}
```

In this case, the function checks if the position is within the dynamic array length. Otherwise, it throws a string which will tell the user the position they chose was out of bounds. So there are ways to use a throw statement without a try and catch block (but try and catch are used together, cannot exclude one).